# How to set checked radio button using name and attr in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, radio-button

I am working with some radio input and want to set them checked while edit function. I used ajax response. I have to set them checked.

The code sample is following:

```
    <form>
Group 1:
    <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_a" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_b" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_c" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_d" value="4" />

Group 2:
    <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_a" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_b" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_c" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_d" value="4" />

Group 3:
    <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_a" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_b" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_c" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_d" value="4" />


</form>
```

I get from ajax response the following:

> var ans_name = ans1,ans2,ans3;
>   var str = ans_c,ans_a,ans_d;

That means i have to set checked the 3rd radio input of gruop 1 and so on.

How can i set checked the corresponding radio button by jquery?

Comment: Add the code you've tried to solve the problem.

Comment: which all radio button you want to check?

Comment: Also what is ans_1 & ans_c are they comma separated string or what?

Comment: they are comma separated string. I want to set check the following:  3rd radio of group 1, 1st radio of group 2, 4th radio of group 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select based on [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and update the `checked` property.

```js
var ans_name = 'ans1,ans2,ans3';
var str = 'ans_c,ans_a,ans_d';

// split the string into array by ,
var names = ans_name.split(','),
  val = str.split(',');

// iterate over names array
names.forEach(function(v, i) {
  // generate the selector and get jQuery object using that
  $('[name="' + v + '"][str="' + val[i] + '"]')
    // update the property
    .prop('checked', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Group 1:
  <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_a" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_b" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_c" value="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_d" value="4" /> Group 2:
  <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_a" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_b" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_c" value="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_d" value="4" /> Group 3:
  <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_a" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_b" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_c" value="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_d" value="4" />


</form>
```

---

Or generate a single selector using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods.

```js
var ans_name = 'ans1,ans2,ans3';
var str = 'ans_c,ans_a,ans_d';

var names = ans_name.split(','),
  val = str.split(',');


$(names.map(function(v, i) {
      // geneate the selector
      return '[name="' + v + '"][str="' + val[i] + '"]';
    })
    // join the selectors
    .join(','))
  // update the property
  .prop('checked', true)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Group 1:
  <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_a" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_b" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_c" value="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_d" value="4" /> Group 2:
  <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_a" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_b" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_c" value="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_d" value="4" /> Group 3:
  <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_a" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_b" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_c" value="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_d" value="4" />


</form>
```

Comment: @Md.ShamvilHossain : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Explode names and value with data what you get from response and check through loop and you will get radio checked with the correct answer.

```js
var ans_name = "ans1,ans2,ans3";
var str = "ans_c,ans_a,ans_d";

var checkbox_names = ans_name.split(",");
var values = str.split(",");

$(checkbox_names).each(function(index, value){
  $("[name='"+value+"'][str='"+values[index]+"']").prop("checked",true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form>
Group 1:
    <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_a" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_b" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_c" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans1" str="ans_d" value="4" />

Group 2:
    <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_a" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_b" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_c" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans2" str="ans_d" value="4" />

Group 3:
    <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_a" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_b" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_c" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="ans3" str="ans_d" value="4" />
```